# How to share templates and renderings between multiple JSS apps?

Tags: jss

I am exploring Sitecore JSS, and able to create new renderings, templates for my app.

Since we've to create all templates and renderings for the given App, wondering how can we create templates, and renderings that can be shared across multiple apps?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure jss app to use same  namespace, like templates/project/app1 etc. Instead of application name based locations. But you need to share code between this apps for  templates and components (elements you choose to share) .

Check default JSS app config for options you can configure. You can share almost everything including content, config, page structure, media.

Drawback is that you share everything of given item type or nothing since this items are in that same place.

Consider if this is still 2 apps or just one with different content.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So for better maintenance is it possible if I create an App without content, which can contain shared templates, renderings, media, etc. and then can be used in different apps? I can take a look.